# Word that describes what will be a collection of a particular type of document

Tags: single-word-requests

Apologies in advance for not being able to provide a sample sentence as specified in the `single-word`requests` tag, but this context/application is actually just a **folder name** (i.e. a paper file folder or computerized project folde).  I am hoping for a short, meaningful, descriptive word that will:

**encompasses the implication of `"a particular collection of documents"`.**

This may be impossibly broad because `"anthology"` or `"collection"` don't work in this context so I think I will have to refine this further to a more specific context.

The context presently in my mind: A collection of documents that may include for one or more people (please let me know if a different word should be used if it is personal or collective) include:

- biographies
- cover letters
- resumes
- specifically requested application documents

I considered

- `"Personal documents"` (but this is far to vague)
- `"Applications"` (but the content is not really an application, it may be used IN an application, but in and of itself, it's not really an application)

Comment: 'Applicant Information'?

Comment: Does it have to be a single word? You mention the 2-word "Personal documents" as being far too vague (which I agree with), but would two/three-word names that don't suffer [as much] from vagueness be welcome?

Comment: @PapaPoule "PersonalDocuments", "Personal_Documents" ...  All good ways to get around space delimitation limitations in some applications on computers.  That being said, the application is for a filing system so it's not ideal for too verbose of a solution, but I welcome you proposals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [dossier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dossier) defined by Merriam Webster as

> A group of papers that contain detailed information about someone or some thing.
>
> File containing detailed records on a particular person or subject.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response!  I like it - I think it will work.  If in about a day this remains the best option, I will accept it.

Comment: But "dossier" refers to a group of papers on a *single* topic, as your quoted definitions confirm. OP says that the collection "may include for one or more people" - so it's not clear to me whether OP's 'collection' is all on a *single* topic.

Comment: @TrevorD Op will have to use it smartly.

Answer (score 1):

Not a single-word name, but if it’s a sub-file of a file whose name already includes “Applications,” you could call it “**Supporting Documentation**,” which [this *About Careers* article](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/jobsearchglossary/g/supporting-documentation.htm) describes in paragraph 2 as including:
“a resume, a cover letter, transcripts, writing samples, Veterans' Preference documents, portfolios, certifications, a reference list, letters of recommendation, and other supporting documentation as specified in the job posting.”

If it’s a stand-alone file (or maybe even if it isn’t), you should probably add a third word, i.e., “Applicant’s” (or Applicants’ if it includes documents from more than one applicant):
“Applicant’s/Applicants’ Supporting Documentation”

Answer (score 0):

A term that is a little more generic would be [**bundle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bundle).

> a group of things fastened together for convenient handling